Is the writer or artist liable for a copyright violation?
Suppose a writer hires an artist to paint some illustrations for a children's book. The writer then self-publishes the book. Later, it is revealed that the artist stole all of the illustrations and the original owner of the artwork wants to sue. Is the writer liable for the copyright violation?

Both are liable
The Publisher
The publisher is the one that makes unlicensed copies of the artwork, so the publisher is liable for copyright infringement. Since the writer is the publisher, they are liable.
Having been duped to buy a worthless license from someone who couldn't give a license for they had no right to give one does not clear the copyright infringement, but might make the victim an "innocent infringer", with much lower recoverable damages.
If the publisher ordered an infringing artwork made by the artist, that makes them a wilful infringer.
The "Artist"
By making a copy of the artwork and selling it to the the publisher, the "Artist" made an unlicensed copy and thus is liable for copyright infringement. Knowing that they had no license to sell, they are most likely a "wilful infringer", which impacts the amount from recoverable damages.
They're also liable for fraud against the publisher and removal of copyright management information.

If the writer specifically directed the artist to copy the artwork, that would remove the "innocent" part of the infringement, right? Would the artist still be liable if they're "just following orders"?

No, following orders does not make something allowable ever.

"Following orders does not make something allowable ever": this statement does not address Barmar's question, which isn't about the permissibility of the act but about the artist's liability.

@phoog let me rephrase: being ordered to infringe copyright does not take the liability away from the artist.

Why is "Artist" in quotes but "Publisher" not? Is this meant to throw shade at artists who unwittingly commit infringement, or something else?

@preferred_anon because as the facts are offered, no art was done by the "artist" but con art.

@preferred_anon The question and answer are both about situations where the resulting artwork is a knowing infringement on the part of the person providing it to the writer/publisher.  There was no mention or indication of unwitting infringement on that side of things until you raised it.

@Chronocidal Of course, you are right. sorry, I must have badly misread when I posted my comment! (mods feel free to clean that up, this mini-thread serves no further purpose)

There are two aspects here: One, printing and selling the book is copyright infringement. You are not allowed to do that unless you convince the copyright holder to give you permission, whether the situation is your fault or not.
On the other hand, If you hire someone, and they do something illegal, the person hired is responsible, and you are possibly responsible depending on the circumstances.
So in a different situation - say your printer stole a truckload of paper to print your book - we would have to decide whether you have any responsibility for the crime depending on the circumstances. If you said “I need these pictures tomorrow and I don’t care what you have to do” that would likely make you responsible. If the printer said “I have no paper” and you told him where to find a truck full of paper, you’d be responsible.

@Jen “Will anyone rid me of that troublesome priest”…

The liability of the publisher for the printer's theft is different depending on whether the printer is an independent supplier or an employee.  The phrase "your printer" doesn't specify.
